# Query property across multiple DbSets in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have quite a number of `DbSet`s hanging off of my `DbContext`.  The generic type for each of these DbSets derives from a common base class.

How can I query a common property in the base class across all of the DbSets?

To illustrate, say for instance I have the following two DbSets:

```
public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
```

Both `Person` and `Vehicle` derive from `EntityBase`.

```
public class Person : EntityBase {
...
}

public class Vehicle : EntityBase {
...
}
```

Say `EntityBase` is defined as follows:

```
public class EntityBase {
    public virtual string ExampleProperty { get; set; }
}
```

How can I select the values of `ExampleProperty` across all of the DbSets? For my contrieved example I could do a simple union, but I am looking for an easy way to query across all DbSets holding types deriving from `EntityBase`, since I have hundreds of them.

I can query the change tracker as follows, but that will only work for entities with pending changes.

```
dbContext.ChangeTracker
         .Entries<EntityBase>()
         .Select(obj => obj.Entity)
         .Select(obj => obj.ExampleProperty);
```

How can I do the same thing for all entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to grab the data I need using the following query (I prefer the fluent API):

```
dbContext.GetType().GetProperties()
.Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
.Where(p => p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>))
.Where(p => p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First().IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityBase)))
.SelectMany(p => (IEnumerable<EntityBase>)p.GetValue(dbContext, null))
.Select(obj => obj.ExampleProperty);
```

Unfortunately, the SQL generated is querying all columns for each of the DBSet types which is pulling quite a bit of data into memory.